# Confusions with reference in c++

Tags: c++

In *The C++ programming language*, it said "a reference cannot be made to refer to a different object after its initialization." However, when I wrote the code below, it printed 20, which means that the reference refer to another object.

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
int& ref = a;
ref = b;
cout << ref << endl;
```

However, when I wrote the code below, it printed 10, the vaule of a.

```
int a;
int b;
int& ref = a;
ref = b;
a = 10;
b = 20;
cout << ref << endl;
```

Why does this happen? How should I understand C++ reference?

Comment: try printing `a` at the end of your first case

Comment: _"How should I understand C++ reference?"_ : You cannot modify what a reference points at.  Initializing a reference type is not the same as assigning to one.

Comment: After `int& ref = a;`, `ref` means exactly the same thing as `a`. The first is equivalent to `int a = 10; int b = 20; a = b;`, the second to `int a; int b; a = b; a = 10; b = 20;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the line

```
int& ref = a;
```

You set `ref` to be a reference to the variable `a`. You then set the *value* of this object to be the value of `b` in the next line:

```
ref = b;
```

Note that `a` will now have the value of `b` (which since you haven't initialised it yet will be zero).

Next, you set the *value* of `a` to be 10

```
a = 10;
```

At this point `ref` will also be set to be 10, since it is a reference to `a`. You then set the *value* of `b` to be 20. But this makes no difference to `ref` as it is it is a reference to `a`, which is still 10.

So, when you print out `ref`, you get the value of `a` - i.e. 10.

Comment: *(which since you haven't initialized it yet will be zero)* Don't count on that. It only MIGHT be zero if `a` is an automatic variable local to a function, and the `cout << ref << endl;` suggests a function is involved.

Comment: True. Also depends on the compiler you are using.

Answer (score 3):

`ref = b` does not mean "ref should now reference b".
It means "Copy the value of b to the variable referenced by ref".

So this code:

```
int& ref = a
ref = b;
a = 10;
```

Is equivalent to

```
a = b;
a = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

A reference is just alias. It does not have separate memory. So when you write:

```
int a = 10; 
int b = 20;
int& ref = a; //ref has same address a a. Its just alias
ref = b; //value of b assigned to ref, ref still points to same address
cout << ref << endl;
```

It says that `ref` is alias for `a`. So same address as `a`.

When you write `ref = b`, you are assigning the value of `b` to `ref`, in turn to `a`.

So, when you print `ref`, `a` and `b` will both print the same value i.e 20, but their addresses are not the same. `a` and `b` still take up different addresses.

In the second example of yours, `ref` is alias for `a`. Then you assign a value of `b` to `ref`. Still `ref` has the address of `a`. Then you changed the value of `b`. So `b` gets a new value but `ref` is still pointing to the address of `a`, which does not get modified.

Hope this clears up your confusion.

To understand better, try printing the addresses and values of variables. That way, you will get better understanding.

Comment: A reference does not have a memory address of its own. It might not even be implemented using a variable at all. Once a reference is bound to something, querying the reference for its address will return the address of the thing it refers to instead. Just like assigning a value to a reference will assign to the thing it refers to. And reading a value from a reference will read from the thing it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small program that tries to illustrate the difference between references and pointers. Hopefully this will help you see how the "cannot be made to refer to a different object" works:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    int* p = &a;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << *p << ". p points to a\n";

    *p = 11;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << *p << ". Changing p changes a\n";

    a = 12;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << *p << ". Changing a changes p\n";

    p = &b;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << *p << ". p points to b\n";

    *p = 21;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << *p << ". Changing p now changes b, but a is unchanged as p no longer points to it\n";

    b = 22;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << *p << ". Changing b changes p\n";

    int& r = a;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << r << ". r references a\n";

    r = 13;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << r << ". Changing r changes a\n";

    a = 14;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << r << ". Changing a changes r\n";

    r = b;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << r << ". The value of r is set to the value of b, but r still references a and thus a changes too\n";

    b = 23;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << r << ". Changing b does NOT change r\n";

    r = 24;
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << r << ". Changing r only changes a\n";
}
```

```
10, 20, 10. p points to a
11, 20, 11. Changing p changes a
12, 20, 12. Changing a changes p
12, 20, 20. p points to b
12, 21, 21. Changing p now changes b, but a is unchanged as p no longer points to it
12, 22, 22. Changing b changes p
12, 22, 12. r references a
13, 22, 13. Changing r changes a
14, 22, 14. Changing a changes r
22, 22, 22. The value of r is set to the value of b, but r still references a and thus a changes too
22, 23, 22. Changing b does NOT change r
24, 23, 24. Changing r only changes a
```

The point here is that with the pointer you can do `p = &b` and refer to a different object. This is impossible with a reference.